# How to open one EditForm.aspx Page in Classic mode, In a Modern Experience SPOnline env.

Tags: javascript, spfx, modern-experience

I do **not** want to switch the whole SiteCollection back to Classic.
Users are very happy with the Modern Experience

I want to open the EditForm in Classic mode only once.. so my UserCustomAction ScriptLink executes

When Modern Experiences were in preview we had `&TryNewExperience=true` to switch from Classic to Modern

But the reverse `&TryNewExperience=false` does not work

Searched for some 10 minutes, but get Switch-back-to-everything-Classic answers only...
*I am probably searching with the wrong words*